# node.js xml to json objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

In Node, I'm trying to migrate an XML structure into JSON, which would allow me to access specific nodes without arrays, but guess issue is common for all ECMA related languages

Basically I'm looking for a way of doing this:

```
var siteSettings = configuration.settings.siteSettings
var site1 = siteSettings[0];
var site1Name = site1.name;
```

where the XML is this

```
<configuration>
  <settings>
    <siteSettings>
      <siteSetting name="site1" path="path1"/>
      <siteSetting name="site2" path="path2"/>
    <siteSettings>
  </settings>
  <modules>
    <module name="module1" action="action1">
    <module name="module2" action="action2">
  </modules>
</configuration>
```

However, the XML parser modules I found does something like this (pseudo):

```
configuration:{
  settings:
    [siteSettings:
      [siteSetting: {name: "site1", path: "path1"}, 
       siteSetting: {name: "site2", path: "path2"}]};
```

What do you reccommend - am I even on right track?

Comment: XML can sometimes be tricky to convert to JSON, because they aren't exactly equivalent.  There are some things you can do in XML which you can't easily do in JSON.  I would advise using some module kinda like DOM.  Where the XML is parsed, but there is methods to select specific XML data.

Comment: [fast-xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser) is one of the options to parse XML to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
{  
   "configuration":{  
      "settings":{  
         "siteSettings":[  
            {  
               "name":"site1",
               "path":"path1"
            },
            {  
               "name":"site2",
               "path":"path2"
            }
         ]
      },
      "modules":[  
         {  
            "name":"module1",
            "path":"action1"
         },
         {  
            "name":"module2",
            "path":"action2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that the XML format will never change, you could then normalize the data that you received from XML parser. This is an example based off of your psuedo XML.

```
// Example of parsed XML
var xml = {
  configuration: {
    settings: [{
      siteSettings: [{
          siteSetting: {name: "site1", path: "path1"}
        },{
          siteSetting: {name: "site2", path: "path2"}
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
};


var rawSiteSettings = xml.configuration.settings[0].siteSettings;
var siteSettings = [];

// Normalize siteSettings from XML
for(var i=0; i<rawSiteSettings.length; i++){
  siteSettings.push(rawSiteSettings[i].siteSetting);
}

console.log(siteSettings); // this would equal [{name:"site1"}, {name:"site2"} ect...]

// Helper to search object by value
var getPropertyByName = function(data, value){
  for(var prop in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      if(data[prop].name === value){ // Checking by name only
        return data[prop];
      }
    }
  }
};

var firstSite = getPropertyByName(siteSettings, "site1");
var firstSiteName = firstSite.name;
var firstSitePath = firstSite.path;

console.log('Name: ' + firstSiteName); // site1
console.log('Site Path: ' + firstSitePath); // path1
```

Edit: You will need to scroll.

Edit 2: What I mean by normalizing is: you are taking 'settings' and 'siteSettings', which are both arrays inside of objects, and putting them into a workable format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple node-module xml2js
Please refer below link :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js